# If I want to learn NFT programing FAST, where should I start?

Tags: solana-program

I have no coding experience other than taking some classes in college almost 8 years ago.

I'm planning Solana, but I heard I have to learn Rust first. TBH I'd rather take the fastest route since I run a self-employed business. Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's from where I learned and make an earning. It took me 1 week but it all depends upon your skill level and past programming experience.

YouTubers:

- [Josh's DevBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AAtfPHEMbA&list=PL53JxaGwWUqCr3xm4qvqbgpJ4Xbs4lCs7)
- [Coding & Crypto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsKbzsN7q1o&list=PLUBKxx7QjtVnU3hkPc8GF1Jh4DE7cf4n1)

Udemy:

- [Learn With Arjun](https://www.udemy.com/course/solana-developer/#reviews)

Note: Remember if you are stuck anywhere you can always ask questions in the Solana community.

Happy learning ;)

Comment: Once you complete these tutorials, then also look into updating metadata, freezing tokens, and burning NFTs/ coins.

Answer (score 1):

Rust only comes at play if you want to create a custom smart contract.In solana program/smart contracts are stateless unlike EVM chains so it allows you to do many things with minimal coding knowledge. For example in solana to create a token or to mint a NFT you dont have to deploy any smart contract. You can use the existing CLIs and tools to do so.